# In JS when I 'alert()' the value of an argument passed to the function, it prints out [object Object], why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is very simple, I want to pass string values to a JS function so that it can show them in the usual alert popup.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="clickit" onclick="myfun('dog','cat')"> Hello </div>
```

and here's the JS:

```
('.clickit').click(function myfun(){
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        alert(arguments[i]);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it's not working properly, it prints out: [object Object].

Also, it's looping only once even if there are 2 arguments. 
I followed what is described in here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp), yet it isn't working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not think this question is a duplicate and I do not think it should have been closed.

Comment: @J4G: It's clearly not a duplicate, at least not of the question that it was marked as a duplicate of, so I reopened it.

Comment: @Guffa This has been closed and reopened?  There appears to be no history being shown?

Comment: `arguments[0]` is a _jQuery.Event_ instance when invoked through the `.click` attachment (so `.toString`ing it gives `"[object Object]"`), the _onclick_ attribute gives a _ReferenceError_ when invoked

Comment: You are mixing two things here. Why are you using an inline event handler **and** use jQuery to bind another event handler? I recommend to spend some more time reading http://learn.jquery.com/events/ and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html first.

Comment: @JamesThorpe was going to post a JS Fiddle before i reopened it. Guffa's is better anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no function with a public name `myfun`. The function in the event handler is a named function expression, so the name is only available inside that function. The code in the click attribute will crash and you can find an error message for that in the error log.

When the function is called as an event handler there is only one argument; the event object.

To call the function with parameters from the event you need a named function:

```
function myfun(){
  var i=0;
  for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    alert(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Then you can call it from the click attribute:

```
<div class="clickit" onclick="myfun('dog','cat')"> Hello </div>
```

or you can bind an event handler from code that calls the function:

```
$('.clickit').click(function(){
  myfun('dog','cat');
});
```

Demo:

```js
function myfun(){
  var i=0;
  for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    alert(arguments[i]);
  }
}

$('.clickit').click(function(){
  myfun('dog','cat');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="myfun('dog','cat')"> Hello </div>

<div class="clickit"> Hello </div>
```

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes, of course. Thanks, I corrected that.

Comment: Might want to link this too: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ .

Comment: If I was inserting this code in a <script> </> tag  it would work, unfortunately that is not the case and just declaring a function like you did would not even call the function at all. Is there an other method that allows me to obtain what I need without the conflict of `.click/onclick=""`? Can I pass arguments to the function from html without calling it in `onclick=""`? Or can I describe the function for that class without the `.click` or `.on("click",...) ` procedure?

Comment: @FebioMosca: I just forgot to remove `);` after the function definition. I edited the code above and added a demo that shows both ways to use the function.

Comment: I need to pass the needed arguments from the HTML code, not from JS. Furthermore if I run your code snippet here on StackOverflow it doesn't work at all, if I run it in JSFiddle only the second "Hello" works and that is because the values are passed directly from JS, which is NOT what I need. I need to resolve the `.click/onclick=""` conflict while still passing values from HTML and associating the function myfun() with the div's class. If that's even possible...

Comment: @FebioMosca: Are you trying it in Chrome? It doesn't allow alerts in the snippets. If you try it in JSFiddle you need to make sure that the code is not in a wrapper so that the function is global, otherwise you can't reach it from the code in the onclick attribute. Here is a fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/ugo0m71v/

Comment: Thanks, now I got it :)